# In SQL, how to change the value in the table at the time of query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table names TableA like

```
Id |Student | Subject | 
=======================
1  | XY     | M       |
2  | YZ     | Ph      |
3  | DD     | CH      |
4  | HH     |  M      |
=======================
```

At the time of query i want to show Math instead of M, Physics instead of Ph and so forth. 
I dont want to change in the table but in the query, is this possible in sql server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) :

```
select case subject 
                    when 'M' then 'Math' 
                    when 'Ph' then 'Physics' 
                    else subject end
from TableA
```